# My ODE system's state consists only of the differences in the location and velocities of two particles. How can I solve for the absolute values?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, simulation

I have a linear ODE describing the relative motion of two particles ($T$ and $M$) in 3 dimensions. I have the individual *accelerations* for $T$ and $M$, but the location and velocity coordinates are only given as the *difference* between the two particles (So e.g. in the $x$ direction the location difference is $D_x=T_x-M_x$ and the velocity difference is $\dot{D_x}=\dot{T_x}-\dot{M_x}$)

All in all the state vector is

$$ \vec{x} = (D_x,D_y, D_z,  \dot{D_x}, \dot{D_y}, \dot{D_z}, \ddot{T_x}, \ddot{M_x}, \ddot{T_y} \ddot{M_y}, \ddot{T_z}, \ddot{M_z}) $$

and I have a matrix $A$ which gives the dynamics

$$\dot{\vec{x}} = A\vec{x}$$

**Question**

I'd like to (given some specified initial conditions), solve for the *absolute* locations and velocities of the two particles $M$ and $T$. Is this possible?

Comment: For clarity would you give an example of $A$?

Comment: Can't you just solve for $x(t)=e^{A\,t}x(0)$ and use that to calculate the interested value?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen That's precisely the question. Given $x(t)$ (the state vector at time $t$, which I know how to solve for), with the *differences* of positions and velocities, how can I find the actual, absolute, locations of both particles?

Comment: You won't get absolute positions if you don't know the absolute initial values of $T_x, T_y, T_z$.

Comment: @Aruralreader I *do* know the initial (absolute) values, but the dynamics only give me the *difference* from there on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help a bit. I'm changing notation on you, just to make it easier to type, but I think you'll get the idea.

You have the state vector
\begin{equation}
 X = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  M - T \\
  M' - T' \\
  M'' \\
  T''
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and the system of differential equations $X' = AX$ it satisfies.
You don't say much about $A$ but I'll assume the system is linear and
consistent and of the form
\begin{equation}
 A =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & I & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & I & -I \\
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
  b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and the $a$s and $b$s also
are $3 \times 3$ matrices. Augment $X$ with $M$ and $M'$ to get a new state
vector
\begin{equation}
 S = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  M \\
  M' \\
  M - T \\
  M' - T' \\
  M'' \\
  T''
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Then you have $S' = B S$ where
\begin{equation}
 B =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & I & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & I & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & I & -I \\
  0 & 0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
  0 & 0 & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 
 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
If you also know initial conditions $M(0)$ and $M'(0)$ you can
solve it to get all the information you need.